# Read csv with dd.mm.yyyy in Python and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, date-parsing

I am reading a csv file with German date format.
Seems like it worked ok in this post:

[Picking dates from an imported CSV with pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025671/picking-dates-from-an-imported-csv-with-pandas-python)

However, it seems like in my case the date is not recognized as such.
I could not find any wrong string in the test file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style
from pandas import DataFrame

style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True)
df[:5]
```

[image: table]

This results in:

[image: screenshot]

So, the Column with the dates is not recognized as such.
What am I doing wrong here?
Or is this date format simply not compatible?

- OSX 10.10.3
- Anaconda conda 3.13.0
- Python 3.4.3-0
- iPython notebook 3.1.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use `parse_dates=True` then `read_csv` tries to [parse the *index* as a date](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). 
Therefore, you would also need to declare the first column as the index with `index_col=[0]`:

```
In [216]: pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])
Out[216]: 
            morgens  mittags  abends
Datum                               
2015-03-16      382      452     202
2015-03-17      288      467     192
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the `Datum` column to be an index, you could use
`parse_dates=[0]`  to explicitly tell `read_csv`  to parse the first column as dates:

```
In [217]: pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=[0])
Out[217]: 
       Datum  morgens  mittags  abends
0 2015-03-16      382      452     202
1 2015-03-17      288      467     192
```

---

Under the hood `read_csv` uses `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse date strings:

```
In [218]: import dateutil.parser as DP

In [221]: DP.parse('16.03.2015', dayfirst=True)
Out[221]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 16, 0, 0)
```

Since `dateutil.parser` has no trouble parsing date strings in `DD.MM.YYYY` format, you don't have to declare a custom date parser here.

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dtm = lambda x: dt.strptime(str(x), "%d.%m.%Y")
df["Datum"] = df["Datum"].apply(dtm)
```

Answer (score 3):

use the date_parser parameter of read_csv to pass a custom date parsing function (a lambda that wraps strptime with the relevant date format)

[pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: `date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')` It was in my case.